# Сортировка по трём таблицам, возможно JOIN

Tags: php, join

*Я новичок в программировании, но тут мне попалась задача, решение которой меня заинтересовало.
В некоторой степени я знаком с mysql, правда пишу с помощью RedBeanPHP, плохо знаком с JOIN'ами, может в этом и есть проблема.*

**Собственно задача:**

Имеется БД с 3мя таблицами

1. Товары (id, Название, Категория, Цена)
2. Свойства товаров (id, Название свойства)
3. Значение свойств товаров (id, id_Товара, id_Свойства, Значение).

Есть набор свойств товара — цвет, размер, новинка. Необходимо выбрать все новинки зеленого цвета и вывести их на странице (верстка не имеет значения, просто в читаемом виде). В списке должна быть информация о размере и цвете товара.

Кто может подсказать решение или наставить на нужный путь к решению задачи? Рекомендуют использовать JOIN.

Comment: Домашние задания нужно выполнять самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно JOIN.С твоей структурой это делается так

```
SELECT t1.Название, t1.категория, t3.Название свойства, t2.значение свойства 
FROM product_table as t1 
JOIN attribute_value_table as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_товара 
JOIN attribute_table as t3 ON t3.id = t2.id_Свойства
Where t3.Название_свойства = "цвет" AND t2.значение_свойства = "зеленый"
```